# Xamarin.Forms 2.1.0.6521 - UWP Not Hitting OnStart / OnSleep methods

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app setup using iOS/Android/UWP. I'm using the latest version (2.1.0.6521 as of 3/1)

When I run the UWP app and have breakpoints set, it hits the main `App` constructor, however none of the other methods listed below:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
```

Is there something special that needs to happen for Forms to hit these methods?

Comment: I'd imagine this is a bug. Xamarin is full of bugs. Check [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?cmdtype=runnamed&list_id=197655&namedcmd=FormsAll) for existing bugs but if not file it with a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem found in the version of the library Xamarin.Form V2.0.0.6482.
After updating the package Nuget in version V2.3.0.46 pre3, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle of an UWP app is different from the lifecycle of an Android app. Please refer to the official document [App lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).

By default, it is something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
}

...

private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

You can follow the tutorial [Adding a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/) to get start. These methods are called in the App.xaml.cs file of an UWP project

Addition: There are a lot of [Xamarin.Forms Samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/All/), you can download them .

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already successfully added the UWP to my Xamarin Forms project. So UWP doesn't hook into the PCL shared code for OnStart/OnSleep/OnResume? I'd have to have specific code living in the UWP project?

Comment: @aherrick, I probably made a mistake in my answer, I thought that OnStart/OnSleep/OnResume are the lifecycle of android project(I developed android projects before, but never used xamarin, sorry.), turns out in a xamarin project, these are in the PCL shared code. I'm not able to find some official document for this question, but base on the sample code, I think you are right, UWP doesn't hook into the PCL shared code for OnStart/OnSleep/OnResume(Thank you for letting me know this). This is only my personal opinion, not an official answer, can we consider this just as a discussion between us?